# Is there a way to change the webbing on this picnic chair?

Tags: repair

This picnic chair has lasted many years but now the webbing is fraying.

I do not see a way to change the webbing.

Is there a way to change the webbing?  (How?)

Thanks.
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you can:

https://www.patioslingsite.com/products-page/chair-replacement-slings/replacement-chair-sling-1pc/

On your chairs, seems like there are caps at the tops and bottoms of the sides that you can probably slide the old sling off.

It's probably worth posting the brand here if you really want to replace them.

Good luck!

Comment: That site looks promising, but the widths are too small and two wide.  I did not find a name plate with a brand or model. The width from the outside of the two sides of the back is a bit more than 18".

Comment: I just checked that site, and it allows you to specify the width in incrementals as well as length the same. I saw 18" plus fractions. Try again.